# Getting Error while updating multi user filed using power automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, updatelistitems

I am trying to update the list item using power automate "Update Item" action. The list item has a multiuser mandatory field and I am setting below claims array to the field after clicking "Switch to input entire array" option available against the field.

```
[
  {
    "Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|Test1@abc.com",
    "Email": "Test1@abc.com"
  },
  {
    "Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|Test2@abc.com",
    "Email": "Test2@abc.com"
  }
]
```

The same was working fine since few days back when I built the automate. Since today morning this throwing below error.

"The 'inputs.parameters' of workflow operation 'Update_item' of type 'OpenApiConnection' is not valid. Error details: The API operation does not allow writing a value for parameter 'item/Approvers[0]/Email'. This parameter is read only."

I tried re creating the claims array and re assigning to the field again, but no luck.

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "Email", try with just **Claims**.

```
[
  {
    "Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|Test1@abc.com"
    
  },
  {
    "Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|Test2@abc.com"
    
  }
]
```